# Array works while vector doesn't. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm making a Tic-tac-toe game and i have a board class which contains 9 instances of tile class and does something with them. At first i used a C array to create those instances `Tile board[MAX_TILES]` and everything works fine with them. However i want to use vectors instead since they're safer so i tried the same with vectors `std::vector<Tile> board(MAX_TILES);` but instead i'm getting a bunch of errors in my .cpp file and 2 errors in my .h file.

I'm not used to vectors yet since i've been taught to use C style arrays by our college professors. What am i doing wrong?

Here is my Board.h and the errors, if you need the .cpp i'll provide:

```
#ifndef BOARD_H
#define BOARD_H

#include <SFML\Window.hpp>
#include <vector>

#include "tile.h"

#define MAX_TILES 9

enum Position
{
    TOP_LEFT        = 0,
    TOP_MIDDLE      = 1,
    TOP_RIGHT       = 2,
    MIDDLE_LEFT     = 3,
    MIDDLE_MIDDLE   = 4,
    MIDDLE_RIGHT    = 5,
    BOTTOM_LEFT     = 6,
    BOTTOM_MIDDLE   = 7,
    BOTTOM_RIGHT    = 8
};

class Board
{
private:
    std::vector<Tile> board(MAX_TILES);
    //Tile board[MAX_TILES];
    void positionTiles();
public:
    //Constructors
    Board();
    Board( TileState tileState );
    //Methods
    void clearBoard();
    void drawBoard(sf::RenderWindow& window);

};

#endif
```

the errors 1 and 2 are from .h and others are from .cpp:

```
Error   1   error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'  
Error   2   error C2059: syntax error : 'constant'  
Error   3   error C2677: binary '[' : no global operator found which takes type 'Position' (or there is no acceptable conversion)   
Error   4   error C2228: left of '.setTilePosition' must have class/struct/union    
Error   5   error C2677: binary '[' : no global operator found which takes type 'Position' (or there is no acceptable conversion)   
Error   6   error C2228: left of '.setTilePosition' must have class/struct/union    
Error   7   error C2677: binary '[' : no global operator found which takes type 'Position' (or there is no acceptable conversion)   
Error   8   error C2228: left of '.setTilePosition' must have class/struct/unio
Error   9   error C2677: binary '[' : no global operator found which takes type 'Position' (or there is no acceptable conversion)   
Error   10  error C2228: left of '.setTilePosition' must have class/struct/union    
Error   11  error C2677: binary '[' : no global operator found which takes type 'Position' (or there is no acceptable conversion)   
Error   12  error C2228: left of '.setTilePosition' must have class/struct/union    
Error   13  error C2677: binary '[' : no global operator found which takes type 'Position' (or there is no acceptable conversion)   
Error   14  error C2228: left of '.setTilePosition' must have class/struct/union    
Error   15  error C2677: binary '[' : no global operator found which takes type 'Position' (or there is no acceptable conversion)   
Error   16  error C2228: left of '.setTilePosition' must have class/struct/union    
Error   17  error C2677: binary '[' : no global operator found which takes type 'Position' (or there is no acceptable conversion)   
Error   18  error C2228: left of '.setTilePosition' must have class/struct/union    
Error   19  error C2677: binary '[' : no global operator found which takes type 'Position' (or there is no acceptable conversion)   
Error   20  error C2228: left of '.setTilePosition' must have class/struct/union    
Error   21  error C3867: 'Board::board': function call missing argument list; use '&Board::board' to create a pointer to member 
Error   22  error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type   29
Error   23  error C2228: left of '.setTileState' must have class/struct/union   
Error   24  error C3867: 'Board::board': function call missing argument list; use '&Board::board' to create a pointer to member 
Error   25  error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type   
Error   26  error C2228: left of '.setTileState' must have class/struct/union   
Error   27  error C2677: binary '[' : no global operator found which takes type 'Position' (or there is no acceptable conversion)   
Error   28  error C2228: left of '.getTileSprite' must have class/struct/union  
Error   29  error C2677: binary '[' : no global operator found which takes type 'Position' (or there is no acceptable conversion)       45
Error   30  error C2228: left of '.getTileSprite' must have class/struct/union  
Error   31  error C2677: binary '[' : no global operator found which takes type 'Position' (or there is no acceptable conversion)   
Error   32  error C2228: left of '.getTileSprite' must have class/struct/union  
Error   33  error C2677: binary '[' : no global operator found which takes type 'Position' (or there is no acceptable conversion)   
Error   34  error C2228: left of '.getTileSprite' must have class/struct/union  
Error   35  error C2677: binary '[' : no global operator found which takes type 'Position' (or there is no acceptable conversion)   
Error   36  error C2228: left of '.getTileSprite' must have class/struct/union  
Error   37  error C2677: binary '[' : no global operator found which takes type 'Position' (or there is no acceptable conversion)       49
Error   38  error C2228: left of '.getTileSprite' must have class/struct/union  
Error   39  error C2677: binary '[' : no global operator found which takes type 'Position' (or there is no acceptable conversion)   
Error   40  error C2228: left of '.getTileSprite' must have class/struct/union  
Error   41  error C2677: binary '[' : no global operator found which takes type 'Position' (or there is no acceptable conversion)   
Error   42  error C2228: left of '.getTileSprite' must have class/struct/union  
Error   43  error C2677: binary '[' : no global operator found which takes type 'Position' (or there is no acceptable conversion)   
Error   44  error C2228: left of '.getTileSprite' must have class/struct/union
```

Comment: Would you like to show the .cpp as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this in C++03.

```
std::vector<Tile> board(MAX_TILES);
```

You should use this in c-tor.

```
Board():board(MAX_TILES)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With just a quick look you need to initialize the vector in the constructor of Board rather than in the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

C++03 doesn't support initializer lists. If this is C++11 then you have to use {}.